# múltiples constructores

Tags: java, constructor

Buenos días, Estoy realizando un ejercicio para crear una "máquina registradora", He creado una clase *Productos* donde incluir: *nombre*,*precio por unidad*,*descuento* y *precio de descuento*. El problema está en que si trato de crear varios constructores (uno por tipo de producto) me da error por *duplicar el método*, se que debe haber una manera sencilla de corregirlo, pero no logro solucionarlo salvo que me limite a crear solo dos constructores.
Adjunto el código a continuación. Gracias.

```
public class Productos {
    private static String name;
    private static  float unitaryPrice;
    private static  int amountForDiscount;
    private static  float discount;
//Constructor
public Productos(){  //Primer constructor
    this.name = "cocacola";
    this.unitaryPrice = 1.2f;
    this.amountForDiscount = 3;
    this.discount = 0.75f;          
}
public Productos(String name, float unitaryPrice, int amountForDiscount, float discount){
    this.name = "huevos";
    this.unitaryPrice = 2.0f;
    this.amountForDiscount = 2;
    this.discount = 1.0f;}

public Productos ("leche", 0.5f, 6,0.4f){ //Tercer constructor
    this.name = "leche";
    this.unitaryPrice = 0.5f;
    this.amountForDiscount = 6;
    this.discount = 0.4f;}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los constructores se usan para inicializar, la definición de constructor que estas realizando sería incorrecta. Modifica el segundo Constructor:

```
    public class Productos {
        private static String name;
        private static  float unitaryPrice;
        private static  int amountForDiscount;
        private static  float discount;
    //Constructor
    public Productos(){  //Primer constructor
        this.name = "cocacola";
        this.unitaryPrice = 1.2f;
        this.amountForDiscount = 3;
        this.discount = 0.75f;          
    }

    public Productos(String name, float unitaryPrice, int amountForDiscount, float discount){
        this.name = name;
        this.unitaryPrice = unitaryPrice;
        this.amountForDiscount = amountForDiscount;
        this.discount = discount;
    }

    /*public Productos("leche", 0.5f, 6,0.4f){ //Tercer constructor
        this.name = "leche";
        this.unitaryPrice = 0.5f;
        this.amountForDiscount = 6;
        this.discount = 0.4f;}
    }*/   

}
```

de esta forma instancias tu clase con los valores que deseas de ambas formas:

```
 new Productos("huevos",  2.0f, 2,  1.0f);
```

y

```
 new Productos("leche", 0.5f, 6, 0.4f);
```

En realidad no necesitas crear más constructores.

Comment: Entiendo, te lo agradezco, pero si tengo que llamar a éstas por separado (por ejemplo, llamar al valor  _unitaryPrice_ del producto leche) ¿Cómo lo haría para que el programa lo diferencia de cualquier otro _new Productos_ ?

Answer (score 2):

En Java, los métodos solo pueden recibir variables como argumentos, no valores literales. Por ello, tu tercer constructor falla. Lo que debes hacer es que en otro constructor llames al constructor deseado con la instrucción `this()`. Aquí un ejemplo:

```
public Productos(String name, float unitaryPrice, int amountForDiscount, float discount) {
    this.name = "huevos";
    this.unitaryPrice = 2.0f;
    this.amountForDiscount = 2;
    this.discount = 1.0f;
}

/*
public Productos(){  //Primer constructor
    this.name = "cocacola";
    this.unitaryPrice = 1.2f;
    this.amountForDiscount = 3;
    this.discount = 0.75f;          
}

public Productos ("leche", 0.5f, 6,0.4f){ //Tercer constructor
    this.name = "leche";
    this.unitaryPrice = 0.5f;
    this.amountForDiscount = 6;
    this.discount = 0.4f;}}
*/
public Productos() {
    //esta es la forma en que llamarías al "Tercer constructor"
    //solo se puede llamar 1 vez a otro constructor mediante this()
    //así que debes decidir cuál constructor quedará
    //this("leche", 0.5f, 6, 0.4f);
    //this("cocacola", 1.2f, 3, 0.75f);
}
```

Si no quieres modificar el primer constructor, lo que te recomiendo es crear un método `Productos creaLeche()` donde devuelvas una nueva instancia de `Productos` donde devuelves los datos del producto que quieres:

```
public Productos creaLeche() {
    return new Productos("leche", 0.5f, 6, 0.4f);
}
```

Comment: Respecto a esto, no hay constructores con parametros que tienen valores por defecto? digase: `Productos(String nombre = "Leche") { /* código */ }` ?

Comment: @NaCl no, no hay. Para ello en Java existe la sobrecarga de métodos donde defines dos métodos: `void foo(String s) { ... } void foo() { foo("cadena con valor por defecto"); }`

Comment: De esta manera, si quisiera acceder por ejemplo a uno solo de los valores insertos en este _creaLeche()_ , sería utilizando el punto *.* ? por ejemplo `creaLeche.unitaryPrice`

Comment: @isilion `creaLeche` es un método, no un constructor. Ese método utiliza el constructor de `Productos`. Puedes hacer algo como `Productos leche = Productos.creaLeche(); leche.get...();`